# csv to mysql using php no data inserted

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to upload the contact data of csv to mysql database phbook using php,
but when i check through phpmyadmin or print the data of the database.. i dont see anything, or say the table is empty,

The code i used is as below;

```
    <?php
    /* conenction to DB */

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("phbook", $con);

    /* connection ends*/

    if ( isset( $_FILES['userfile'] ) )
    {
      $csv_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

      if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )
        exit('File not found.');

      $sql = '';

      if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
      {
          while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
          {
              $sql .= "INSERT INTO `contact` SET
                `fname` = '$data[0]',
                `lname` = '$data[1]',
                `phone` = '$data[2]',
                `mob` = '$data[3]',
                `email` = '$data[4]';
              ";
          }
          fclose($handle);
      }

      // Insert into database

      //exit( $sql );
      exit( "Complete!" );
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>CSV to MySQL Via PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <input name="userfile" type="file">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have used the code  the [Import an excel (.csv) into MySQL using PHP code and an HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893501/import-an-excel-csv-into-mysql-using-php-code-and-an-html-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the help of others like me who are seeking for a solution, read this and follow,

I created a database named **csv**, and table named **test**, where the 4 fields are **id** (auto increment and primary) **,  first_name, last_name, email**. I have created a csv file and named it **upload.csv**(doesnt matter what you name it) where there are hundreds of data of individuals in 3 columns like **First Name**, **Last Name** and **Email Address** example:

willie        walker    willie@example.com 
david        cotter    david@sometest.com 
John        Painer    john@domain.com
.......     ..........   ......................
.......     ..........   ......................

Now, create a new php file import_csv_file.php(doesnt matter what you name it) and paste the codes below, save it and run under your webserver..Upload the csv file that we had created and see..  IT WORKS

```
    <?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('csv', $con);

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($file,"r");
            while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
            {

                $f = $fileop[0];
                $l = $fileop[1];
                $e = $fileop[2];
                $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (first_name,last_name,email) VALUES ('$f','$l','$e')");
            }
            if($sql)
            {
                echo "data uploaded successfully";
            }
        }

    ?>

    <body>
    <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <input type="file" name="file" />
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `mysql_query` to execute to query. Right now you only formulate the query as a string (`$sql`) and do nothing further. Just pass this string as a parameter, like:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

You may also want to handle any errors that occur. For instance (from PHP manual):

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

For details, see [PHP manual on mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).